# <context:property-placeholder> erroer in myservelet-servelet.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I am writing Spring mvc using hibernate.I have a property file `database.properties`in which I have defined database configuration.

**database.properties**

[image]

**sdnext-servlet.xml**
[image]
when I am specifying the path in sdnext-servlet.xml it is throwing an exception.
In the above image I am getting an exception.

> cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'context:property-placeholder' must
>   have no character or element information item [children], because the
>   type's content type is empty.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the element without openning for children: 
`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:...."/>`